# Simplify static Select statement by removing unions

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I want to define values statically inside my query, not using any table.

```
SELECT 1 as id, 'one' as value
  UNION
SELECT 2, 'two'
```

Is it possible to simplify this query, to write it without UNIONs?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you use?

Comment: I've added the sql-server-2012 tag.

Comment: @MarekGrzenkowicz I want to select values not to insert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this construct.

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES(1, 'one'), (2, 'two')) a(Id,value)
```

[**SQL FIDDLE TEST**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/15712)